# How to test an algorithm for digital circuit design?

Tags: testing, logic, benchmarking

I want to examine a digital design method with "lgsynth93" benchmark, which is in c language.
My algorithm is written in MATLAB (*.m).
Is there any solution to do that using MATLAB?
However, if I know the circuits, I write the related M-files, manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RTL viewer of LGSynth93 benchmarks, a public domain suite from the 1993 International Logic Synthesis Workshop, can be find By synthesizing their EDIF files, using a synthesizer tool, such as Altera or Synopsys Design Compiler.